# Number of winning combination in Nim

Tags: algorithms, game-theory

I am studying game theory and I am wondering how many winning combinations are possible for Nim game? Suppose, stones = 500 and piles = 5. With these number, there are many initial game positions are possible. like [1, 2, 4, 3, 490], [100, 100, 100, 100, 100], [100, 200, 100, 100], [0, 200, 200, 50, 50] and so on. So basically there are `stones^piles` combinations possible. Among these, some will yield `Xor > 0` and considered as winning possible.

My question is - how many winning initial positions are possible for given `stones` and `piles`? Instead of checking all possible combinations(which is impossible for larger inputs), is there any smart way to solve this?

This is not a homework or programming contest problem.

Comment: what can be the maximum number of stones and piles ?

Comment: Also can each pile have `stones` stones or is it the total number ?

Comment: Suppose maximum piles 10 and stones 300. No, no piles can have `stones` stones. But some piles can be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume there are `k` piles and each pile can have stones in the range `[0,n]`. Then we can find the losing positions ( you can subtract from total to get no. of winning positions ) using dynamic programming. Let the number of bits in binary representation of `n` be `b`. We take a 2-D array called `dp` of size $kx2^b$, where `dp[i][j]` denotes number of ways of assigning no. of stones to first $i$ piles such that xor of no. of stones in these first $i$ piles is $j$. It is easy to see that no. of losing positions is `dp[k][0]`. Now what's left is to come up with the recurrence relation ( I leave the base cases for you to come up with ).

```
           // take care of the base case  
           for i in range 1 to k:
               for j in range 0 to 2^b:
                   dp[i][j] = 0
                   for m in range 0 to 2^b:
                       // first i piles have nim-sum j
                       // ... if first i-1 piles have nim-sum m in the last
                       // ... pile we keep (m xor j) stones
                       dp[i][j] = dp[i][j] + dp[i-1][m]
```

**EDIT**
If $k$ piles in total have $n$ stones , you can again solve it by dynamic programming , but this time keeping a 3-D `dp` array of size $k$x$2^b$x$n$, where `dp[x][y][z]` means number of arrangements of first `x` piles having in total `z` stones and the nim-sum being `y`. Although I point it out that this method would be feasible only for small values of $k$ and $n$ ( in the order of few  hundreds ). Following is a pseudo code ( again take care of base cases, if you have problem with them you could comment )

```
            // take care of base cases
            // our answer would be ( no. of losing ) positions = dp[k][0][n]

            for i in range 1 to k:
                for j in range 0 to 2^b:
                   for l in range 0 to n:
                      dp[i][j][l] = 0
                      for m in range 0 to l:
                            dp[i][j][l] = dp[i][j][l] + dp[i-1][m^j][l-m]
```

Clearly the above method works for small $k$ and $n$ ( you can reduce the memory, which I leave up to you to figure out ).

Comment: Thanks :) Can you give some more insight on case where `k` piles have total `n` stones? May be some pseudo code will be better.

Comment: sure, I will add it.

Comment: I've solved it using top-down approach with memorisation using 3 state `dp[PILE_MAX][XOR_MAX][REST_STONE_MAX]` as you shown. I wrote the recursive function yesterday but overlooked that there are some overlapping structure. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

(added) As I now realise, you are asking for the number when the *total* number of stones is given.

It seems to be easy to count the number of *loosing* positions when the *maximum number* of stones in each pile is a power of two (minus one). Remember that a postion is loosing if the nim-sum of all the piles is zero, that is xor-ing all the bits will give $0$ at each bit position. So if there are $k$ piles each with at most $2^n-1$ stones, for each bit position, half of the initial positions xor's to $0$. So for each of the $n$ bit positions there are $2^k$ possible combinations for the $k$ piles. Half of these, $2^{k-1}$ xor to zero. This is to be combined to for each bit position, so ${(2^{k-1})}^n$. The total number of initial positions is ${(2^{k})}^n$.

For an arbitrary number of stones there is not such a nice formula, I am afraid.

Comment: Thanks! Great Insight :) And what the rules for any `n`, not only for power of 2?

Comment: I believe that the OP is fixing the *total* number of stones, not the maximum number of stones per pile.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks, you are right. Don't see any fast solution to that one.