# Sum of zero nim sum series

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

The problem is proposed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3011248/sum-of-zero-sum-series) and related to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/balls-in-bins-with-pairwise-distance). Given $n$ and $k$, I would like to know how to compute$$\sum_{\substack{x_0 ⊕x_1⊕\cdots⊕x_k=0\\x_i≥0,\ 0≤i≤k\\\sum\limits_{i=0}^kx_i≤n-2k}}\binom{n-k-\sum\limits_{i=0}^kx_i}k$$ in $O(nk·\log n)$ time, where $⊕$ is exclusive or.

Let $\sum_{i=0}^{k}x_i=S$. 
The straightforward method is enumerating $S$ from $0$ to $n-2k$, and using [dynamic programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57980/number-of-winning-combination-in-nim) to count nonnegative solutions to $\begin{cases}&x_0 ⊕x_1⊕\cdots⊕x_k=0 \\&\sum_{i=0}^{k}x_i=S \end{cases}$ (this is the number of winning positions for the first player of a Nim with $k$ piles and a total of $S$ stones, allowing empty piles). But it runs in $O(n^3 k)$ which is too large.

I think there may be some other dynamic programming technique to solve it, but cannot work out that. Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained.

Comment: I've copied the description here.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out an answer. This paper "[Nim Fractals](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.5942.pdf)" by Tanya Khovanova and Joshua Xiong gives a formula to count the solutions to $$\begin{cases} x_0 \oplus \cdots \oplus x_k =0 \\\sum_{i=0}^{k}x_i=S\end{cases}$$ in $O(kS)$. Denote the number as $f(k,S)$. We may utilize $f$ to see that the problem reduces to $\sum_{S=0}^{n-2k}\binom{n-k-S}{k}f(k,S)$. The overall complexity is $O(nk\cdot log(n))$.